# How to get a table cell in aspose slides?

Tags: cell, aspose

I see this sample:
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Creating+a+Table+from+Scratch
...and when I try to use it, I see that the library has changed (I guess) and it needs me to do sth like that:

```
int lIndex = pSld.Shapes.AddTable(pUppLeftPoint.X, pUppLeftPoint.Y, pColumnWidths, pRowWidths);
TableEx lTable = (TableEx)pSld.Shapes[lIndex];
```

(I can only cast to TableEx and not to Table)

But I cannot find how to get the cell's TextFrame. The site says :

```
TextFrame tf = table.GetCell(0, 0).TextFrame;
```

But I have nothing like this...

Am I missing sth?

Any ideas?

**EDIT :**

I found out that my code is for PPTX and the site's code for PPT:

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/453613/facing-performance-issue-due-to-addtable-method-of-pptx.aspx

But, again, how do you get the cell's contents in PPTX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! I got it!
There's an indexer:

```
lTable[i,j]
```